# Why does SELECT ... WHERE id = a returns a result if value is 0

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
Table preview 
Note: 'id' is an integer column (offcourse)

+-------------+
| id | value  |
+----+--------+
| 0  | abc    |
| 1  | def    |
+-------------+
```

**Queries:**
1. Returns `abc`: `SELECT value FROM table WHERE id = 0`
2. Returns `def`: `SELECT value FROM table WHERE id = 1`
3. Returns nothing: `SELECT value FROM table WHERE id = 2`
4. Returns `abc`: `SELECT value FROM table WHERE id = 'a'`

**The question:** Why does query 4 returns `abc`? It should give no results right?

Comment: According to the ANSI SQL standard, case 4 should raise an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL silently converts strings to numbers in a numeric context.

It does so by converting the leading numeric characters (such as digits, minus sign, and decimal point).

If there are no digits, it stops.  So:

```
where id = 'a'
```

is interpreted as:

```
where id = 0
```

Moral:  Never use single quotes around numeric constants -- or constants that should be numbers.

Comment: Can i prevent converting the characters in SQL so it would'nt return results? For example: `WHERE id = NOCONVERT('a')` or something like that

Comment: @RamonBakker - ....don't even provide non-integer input in the first place.  For one thing, if you're using parameterized queries, your driver should be throwing errors if you try.  Why would you want to provide probably invalid input?

Comment: Im creating a function against SQL injection. I know its 99,99% safe, exept for the string value on a integer column (p.s. its also safe against hex-inject and all other known) (p.s. i dont want to use parameterized queries in this case. I know they are safe but anyway)

Comment: If creating function against injection attack why wouldn't you want to use parametrized queries? I

Comment: People suggest to use prepared statements at the most. It's not wrong, but when your query is executed just once per process, there would be a slightly performance penalty.