# SQL converts 'a' to 0 on a integer column. Can i prevent this?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, casting, integer

SQL converts a string (`'a'`) to integer (`0`) on a `integer` column as learned before in:
[Why does SELECT ... WHERE id = a returns a result if value is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084405/why-does-select-where-id-a-returns-a-result-if-value-is-0)

Is there a way to prevent this? For example: `SELECT ... WHERE id = NO_CONVERT_STR('a')` or something like this? I don't want to change the data type of the `id` column

I tried the `CAST('a' AS CHAR)` method without luck

Comment: Please describe why vote down, then i can maybe improve my question

Comment: Why are you passing a string to an integer column in the first place?  Seems like the problem would be whatever is causing that to happen.

Comment: Because sometimes i don't know the data type of the column, and i can't get it by another query

Comment: That's a bad situation.  What's preventing you from finding out?

Comment: http://ideone.com/fork/f93u8d Check if value is integer, if it is, then just run query with value as integer value, else hex it to prevent injection

Comment: Or just use a query parameter so values are treated as *values* instead of *executable code*.  Also doesn't really explain why the column type isn't known.  While the answer below may be correct, I suspect there is a *much* more significant design problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has an option for turning off such conversions on inserts.  I don't believe there is an option to turn off silent conversion.

You can, however, force an error by doing an *explicit* conversion:

```
where id = convert('a' as unsigned)
```

This should generate an error.

Comment: If there is no other solution, this would be the best